# generic query using jpa

Tags: sql, jpa

Consider the following table:

```
|row |name    |last_name   |nacionality |team  
|1   |Adam    |Ritch       |USA         |Titans  
|2   |Scoth   |Buffalo     |USA         |Titans  
|3   |Jhon    |Veron       |USA         |Islanders  
|4   |Dylan   |Schdit      |USA         |Bulls
```

Imagine a form with these fields (name, last_name, nacionality and team) where none field is mandatory.
I need take into account only the fields that the user informed, **for example**: If the user informed nacionality = USA and team = Titans the aplication need to retrieve the rows 1 and 2.

In my **jpa application** I did:

```
 em.createNativeQuery ("select name from info_people where name = ? and last_name = ? and nacionality = ? and team = ?")
```

**Remark**: the "?" was filled with the values inserted by the user, in this case, the 3 and 4 "?" was filled with the values USA and Titans respectively.

But no row was returned, what is wrong with my query?

Comment: So, what did you use as values for the name and last_name parameters? How could these criteria be ignored if they are part of the query?

Comment: So, this is my question, "how to change my query" for the aplicattion take into account only what the user inform. Many times the user can inform name and last name, in other only the name, in other only the team. Do you understand?

Comment: You need to generate the query dynamically, so that it contains only the relevant criteria in the where clause. You can do that by yourself, of use dedicated APIs like the standard JPA2 criteria API, or QueryDSL, for example.

Comment: could you make an example?, using the table above

Comment: Google is your friend: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @JB Nizet comment, indeed you can create your query dynamically based on your user's request, however you can also design you query to consider NULL values, so you would not need the dynamic query build.

You can accomplish it by checking if the values are NULL OR are equal to your column's value. Here's a example:

```
select name from info_people 
 where (? IS NULL OR ? = name)
   and (? IS NULL OR ? = last_name)
   and (? IS NULL OR ? = nacionality)
   and (? IS NULL OR ? = team)
```

Also note that your parameters but be set to NULL before calling the query, otherwise it would not work as expected.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! Glad this solved your problem, be welcome to StackOverflow community ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that when the user hasn't specified a field, you replace it with the string `%`. That way you can use this query:

```
SELECT name FROM info_people WHERE name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ? AND nacionality LIKE ? AND team LIKE ?
```

Comment: Works only for String columns, but also a nice solution.

Comment: Well, those columns are string-typed.